# Is there a rate limit on Softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are running some load test for our product and it includes some REST calls to Softlayer API. 
Sometimes our rest calls (Softlayer) fails to return any value. We are trying 50+ concurrent requests. Are there any limitations on concurrent requests ?

Appreciate any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

There exist a limit of **50 api calls per second**. It is applied per-user.

If you exceed the limit, an exception like this should be displayed:

> "error": "Rate limit of 50 requests for every 1 second(s) exceeded."

Comment: Is there any method to increase the rate limit per-user per second?