# More than one call at a time at Softlayer API

Tags: node.js, api, cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using Node.js to call the Softlayer API. The problem is, when I make two API call at softlayer client, only the first call gets response objects. Rest face an error. Can anyone help me with the information about how many requests can be processed at a time over SoftLayer API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is 50 request for second for each user. See:

[Is there a rate limit on Softlayer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130368/is-there-a-rate-limit-on-softlayer-api)

[What is the 'rate limit' exceeded of SoftLayer API endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437940/what-is-the-rate-limit-exceeded-of-softlayer-api-endpoint)

I recommend to post the error you got and/or part of your code in order to get more further help from node.js or softlayer community.